# Unable to receive messages sent by server in Android GCM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement Android GCM service using http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/  as a reference. I am able to register the emulator at the database but any message sent from the server is not received at the emulator. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try in a real device.

Comment: It does not. Any more suggestions.

Comment: Is there anyone with similar problems with this code

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It's the same as the one in the link. I didn't make any changes to it. The server and client both code are same.

Comment: have you checked in log? it logs registration id. If you have wrote code same in link, then there should be no any problem with emulator or device. I have also implemented the same code.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
        
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

Comment: @ChintanRathod Yes while registering the id is shown fine. I hope the code which I pasted suffice

Comment: Run that php file which i posted in answer, if it provide you push notification in your emulator then it will work for other devices and real time Push Notification also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following PHP file,

```
<?php
//request url
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//your api key
$apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';

//registration ids
$registrationIDs = array('First_Reg_Id','Second_Reg_Id','Third_Reg_Id');

//payload data
$data   = array('title' => 'hi',  'message' => 'Push notification');

$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
                'data' => $data);

//http header
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                 'Content-Type: application/json');

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
 print_r($fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Before that, Replace **Your API key** which is given by google. Replace **First_Reg_Ids** with your emulator's registration code. Remove others if not used.

You just need to run this PHP file and you will get message with title and message. Just parse it.

Comment: @MradulModi can u pls help me i m using same code but unable to run it on emulator ? and even in real device i m getting registration id but failed to send notification from server can u pls guide me